# Changing the value of a input box in HTML within a script

Tags: javascript, html, input, document

Statement In JS HTML5 I have a input box defined as

```
<input type="number" id="Numerator" value=40>
<input type="number" id="Denominator" value=48>
```

I want to change the value of these within a script.

Question: What HTML5 command will allow me to change the value of id="Numerator"?

Example

```
var k = 2
(insert command here to change id="Numerator" to value k)
```

I know how to pull the value using

```
document.getElementbyID("Numerator").value
```

but I cannot figure out how to change the value of that id....
any help would be appreciated and I could not find that value...

Comment: Reason being I want the user to input a value the first time and then those input boxes are inaccessible to the user afterwards but I still want to use those boxes to call on with other scripts

Comment: Did the answer help you in this problem?

Comment: I am going to check it out in a little bit but I am very thankful :) off to work and lets see if this works :)

Comment: Sure. You can let me know if there is still any issues.

Comment: Yes this did work exactly as intended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your `getElementbyID`. It should be `getElementById`:

```js
var k = 2;
document.getElementById("Numerator").value = k;
```

```html
<input type="number" id="Numerator" value=40>
<input type="number" id="Denominator" value=48>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
document.getElementById("Numerator").value = "My value";
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

```
var el = document.getElementbyID("Numerator");
el.setAttribute("ID", "your-new-id");
```

Comment: but he don't want to set an ID instead he want to set the value.

Comment: IDK.."I cannot figure out how to change the value of that id"

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
document.getElementById('Numerator').value = "Set Value To textbox using javascript";
```